# Query rails database, and update highcharts using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts

I have a page which shows a highchar. I'd like to use Javascript to fetch several pieces of information for a specific user. I want to fetch from my database and place it on the highcharts graoh. I have set up a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yPLjR/307/) which shows static data. But

What I am trying to do is:

- Make javascript call a Rails action with parameters.
- Query the rails database(projectHours table).
- Rails returns the response.
- Javascript updates highcharts and maps the information stored in the projectHours table.

So my question is **What if I want to use information from my db?**

Two of the following models

**Effort.rb**

```
class Effort < ActiveRecord::Base              
  belongs_to :project_task
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**Users.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :projects
  has_many :efforts
```

A further note, I think that in my efforts controller I may need to add some form of render action

```
     rails reponds_to do |f| f.json 
    { render :json => some_hash
} 
      end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use jQuery's get function in order to send a GET request to your rails app like so

```
$.get("/efforts/24", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

And in your controller you could do something like

```
def show
  @effort = Effort.find(params[:id])
  # or find by some of the name of time params

  respond_to do |f|
    format.json { render :json => @effort }
  end
end
```

Depending on how you want to render the results you can either let javascript handle the ajax:success by adding in to the original jQuery get

```
$.get("/efforts/24", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } ).success(function(data) {
  alert(data)
  // Or do whatever you want :)
});
```

Or you can change the respond_to to

```
respond_to do |f|
  format.html { render :nothing => true }
  format.js
end
```

And create a show.js.erb in your app/views/efforts directorty. In this file you can use the responded object

```
$('body').html("<h1><%= escape_javaScript(@effort.title) %></h1>").append("
<%=escape_javaScript(@effort.content) %>");
```

Some good tutorials

[Rails and jQuery](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/)
[jQuery GET](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: Thank you for responding, I will take a look into it now